# rails mountable engine - SQLite3::SQLException: no such table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, rails-engines, nested-resources

I am following the Rails [Guide Getting Started with Engines](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/engines.html).  The only thing that is different is that I am using the RubyMine IDE.  I am using ruby 2.5.0 and rails 5.1.5.

Everything has gone smoothly until I reached section 4, "hooking into an application."  Before hooking into an application, I wanted to test that all was well. I tried to create a couple articles and comments using both the engine views and also the rails console.  I can create articles. But I cannot create comments.  I am receiving the error:

```
SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: main.articles: INSERT INTO "blorgh_comments" ("article_id", "text", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
```

I opened the test/dummy/db/development.sqlite3 database in DB Browser for SQLite and I do indeed have a table named "blorgh_comments".

I'm guessing that the "no such table" error is some kind of "downstream error", i.e., rails can't access the table because of some other (unnamed) error.

I set up the migrations per the guide, the nested resources, the views, and partials.  I checked the "special files" mentioned in the guide and they all have the required code (I did not have to change anything).

So I guess the question is, what kind of "underlying" error is likely to trigger this error?

Any help is appreciated.

================ EDIT =================

Engine is now working and I **think** I know why:

The guide told me to create a comments model with an article_id of type integer (obviously the reference to the parent article), like so:

```
rails g Comment article_id:integer text:text
```

Rather than do that, I created the model like so:

```
rails g Comment article:references text:text
```

I was unable to create comments, as noted in my question above.  When I "refactored" the app and created the migration as instructed in the guide, it worked.

Therefore, I assume that the code that generates rails engines does not recognize and/or properly handle the *t.references* directive.  Specifically, I suspect that it tries to create the index within the change method (of the migration) rather than after it (as is the case in a number of other questions / solutions of a similar nature here on StackOverflow).  If I am correct, I think this qualifies as a bug in the implementation of rails engines, but, I won't report it as such because I am not experienced enough to know if that is really the case.

======================== Another Edit =====================

I found this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30108642/rails-engines-with-problems-in-foreign-keys) by @Igor-Belo that says that it is a name spacing issue.  I can use the t.references directive but still need to edit the migration to properly set up the foreign key indexing.